# Is spywareblaster from javacoolsoftware effective when using as standard user on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have installed spywareblaster from [javacoolsoftware](http://www.javacoolsoftware.com/spywareblaster.html) on my Windows 7 laptop. During installation I installed it as a administrator user however I always login to my system as a standard user. (Administrator user is "Admin", while standard user is "Tushar"). During installation it did not create any shortcuts on my standard users desktop. It looks like shortcut and setting are applied to the admin login that installed the software. Will it be effective in my standard user profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spyware blaster uses both system wide methods , and  methods that only work/apply Per user. the protection needs to be applied to the users account also, to have the full use of it.

The existance of the program or icon is meaningless as you know. spyware blaster is fully passive, and not "running", most of the adjustments it makes are in the registry.
 Breaking bad ActiveX so it cannot run, setting sites on the restricted list, blocking the acceptance of certain cookies, and a few tools for securing some holes.  You Should be able to see if the restricted sites, and cookie blocks are still applied in the normal internet options.

Comment: Unfortunately I checked from normal users login and to my surprise some website listed in spywareblaster were able to open via IE!